# A 404 error occurred in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I used zend skeleton application but when i route my module it gives error A 404 error occurred
Page not found.
The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
here is my module.config.php file code:

```
<?php
return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Calendar\Controller\Calendar' => 'Calendar\Controller\CalendarController',
        'Calendar\Controller\Event' => 'Calendar\Controller\EventController',
    ),
),

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'calendar' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/calendar[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action'   => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'       => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Calendar\Controller\Calendar',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'event' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/event[/:action][/:id][/:unixTime][/:allDay]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action'   => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'       => '[0-9]+',
                    'unixTime' => '[0-9]+',
                    'allDay'   => '0|1',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Calendar\Controller\Event',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),

'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'calendar' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

);

How i set the routing in zf2?

Comment: Your route can not be matched by routing anyways. You have two optional parameters which have identical constraints and the router wouldn't be able to know which parameter is meant.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

try this,

```
'defaults' => array(

'__NAMESPACE__' => 'Calendar\Controller',
```

well i am not sure that this is what is causing your problem,
'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Calendar\Controller\Calendar',
Also i compared your module config and i noticed your are missing some code. 
For example, in the default module config of the skeleton app you can see differences,
While developing my project i used this one as a guide and all the routing works. You can try and compare it with yours and see the differences.

```
return array(
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
        // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
        // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
        // using the path /application/:controller/:action
        'application' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/application',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(//e.g. YOUR ARE MISSING THIS LINE
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
        'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
    ),
    'aliases' => array(
        'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
    ),
),
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
// Placeholder for console routes
'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
        ),
    ),
),
```

);

Comment: Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You might get more upvotes that way!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you exactly requires. but if you add a controller extra then you have to add that controller in the application.config.php which is in the config folder in the root.

in the file edit the section and add your controller name

return array(

```
// This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    "your controller name goes here",
),
```